# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError with ViewChildren

Tags: angular

I “fixed” this error but I wanted to make sure i’m not doing something that i shouldn’t be, as this just feels wrong…

Here is my contrived example, I have two components `faqComponent` and `questionAnswerComponent`

```html
<app-faq>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let questionsAnswer of questionsAnswers">
      {{ questionsAnswer.question }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <app-question-answer
     question="1. Why Foo Bar when Baz?"
     slug="why-foo-bar-when-baz"
     [activeSlug]="currentSlug"
  >
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </p>
  </app-question-answer>
    ... // a lot more question answer components
</app-faq>
```

I want the list to be dynamically generated by the questionsAnswer components on the parent component, This is working the way I want by using view children

```
@ViewChildren(QuestionAnswerComponent) questionsAnswers: QueryList<QuestionAnswerComponent>;
```

with the exception that I get a `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` in the log (but it still renders the list for me)

To fix this I found that if i set the faq component change detection strategy to OnPush and then in ngAfterContentChecked trigger a `markForCheck()` it gets rid of that error.

So my questions is why is this bad? or is there another way I should be iterating over the viewChildren?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue addressed in `v8`, having a explicit `static` flag on ViewChildren and ViewContent. So, if you `ng update @angular/core`, the update schematic will add the `static: false` to your `questionAnswers` because it will detect that they are dynamic, and they will be available after `ngAfterViewInit`.

In the other hand, I'm not quite sure if this change improves the change detection and removes the exception, you may upgrade and tell us :D but you approach seems right because that's the way we had to avoid this error in v7, and hopefully it won't happen in v8.
Happy ng-coding!

Comment: interesting, yeah it's gonna be a bit before this project gets upgraded lol. But it is good that i seem to have an understanding or at least we are both wrong haha

Comment: hehehe it could be interesting to reproduce the way you load your data in a StackBlitz to see if we still need to do some manual change detection, I hope not :D

Comment: just commenting back for future reference that v8 does look to address this issue directly which is nice https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration Thanks again Mateo, i'll accept your answer.